# Do your jobs efficiently and we'll chalk one up for the "Haynes"

Tags: meaning

Here's from the movie The Enemy Below (1957)

> This is the captain. I guess you're all
>   waiting for some kind of word.
>   We're tracking an unidentified ship. We're going
>   to try to stay on his tail until morning.
>   We will breakfast early,
>   and go to battle stations at 0530.
>   Don't be surprised if we tangle
>   with a pig-boat a little after dawn.
>   Do your jobs efficiently and we'll
>   chalk one up for the "Haynes". That's all.

What does 'we'll chalk one up for the "Haynes"' mean?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a specific name or character usage (Haynes) in a media setting, and not about the learning the English language.

Comment: @user3169
Haynes is not an character in the movie.
It is not mentioned elsewhere in the movie.
Besides, it has the article "the".

Comment: As in the answer from The Photon, it is a ship's name. Relevant historically but not really relevant to learning English per se.

Comment: @user3169 Some users(including you) thought it might be a character name.
You learned that a character name does not have the article "the". I think this is on topic.

Comment: It's a valid question about English. There's no way to know if this is an established expression or not. In this case, it happens to be the name of a ship, but how would anyone know that it wasn't referring to something more idiomatic? The phrase _win one for the Gipper_ comes to mind, which started as an American football idiom, moved into the [U.S. political arena](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/win-one-for-the-gipper.html), but still gets applied in a more [general sense](http://www.sactownroyalty.com/2014/4/2/5573674/kings-vs-lakers-preview-win-one-for-the-gipper) in sports.

Comment: You can watch the movie on youtube.
I don't copy the link here(for an obvious copyright issue, you know).
You can hear the quoted message at 14:38 on the video.
The name "Haynes" has never been mentioned before.
However, this is a movie. I think most of native English speakers are supposed to understand the meaning of it.

Comment: @user3169 - Expressions like this one are interesting. To the learner, such utterances often sound like established phrases that native speakers would understand. Sometimes, though, that doesn't turn out to be the case. When an O.P. asks about something that turns out to be, say, a specific name or character, I usually oppose closing such questions on ELL because there might be no way for a learner to know better until _after_ they get the answer to their question, and ELL was designed to be a place learners could ask about potentially-established phrases without fear of censure.

Comment: @J.R. In general I agree, though I could not find any usage of this expression other than the mentioned movie quote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The plot synopsis of the film on IMDB tells us,

> During World War II, the **USS Haynes**, an American destroyer escort discovers a German U-boat in the South Atlantic. A deadly duel between the two ships ensues, and Captain Murrell must draw upon all his experience to defeat the equally experienced German commander.

The ship's name is the USS Haynes, and it would colloquially be called "the Haynes".

Answer (score 2):

"Chalk up" is a phrasal verb which means:

1. To earn or score: chalk up points.
2. To credit or ascribe: Chalk that up to experience.

[source.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/chalk+up)

In general, it means to achieve something good.

"Haynes": could be a name of an character in that story or something, so, it could be:

> We will achieve something good for the sake of "Haynes".

Comment: There's no character called Haynes in the movie.
If Haynes is a character, I wonder why it has the article "the".

Comment: From the perspective of *learning English* this answer is perfectly correct. Native speakers (and others with good knowledge of English idioms) can infer no more information than this from the text as cited. It's irrelevant that *some* people might happen to have the "specialist" or otherwise "context-specific" knowledge of exactly who/what "the Haynes" is. That's a matter of *history/culture*.

Comment: Yes, I completely agree with you.@FumbleFingers